# How to find the setup location in an VBScript custom action for InstallShield?

Tags: vbscript, installshield, custom-action

In an InstallShield project I have a VBScript custom action that conditionally needs to execute a certain file packaged with the install.

Normally I get the current directory of a vbs using code such as

```
sCurPath = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName(".")
```

Which, if it returned the location of the Setup.exe that initiated the install, should work.

However when running the install, the current path (on XP) is C:\Windows\system32 instead of the location of the Setup.exe file I was expecting.

Assuming the output of my InstallShield build looks like the following

```
Disk1
->Setup.exe
->ISSetupPrerequisites
-->Req1
-->Req2
-->...
->OtherReqs
-->ConditionallyRunMe.exe
```

How could I run "\OtherReqs\ConditionallyRunMe.exe" from a VBScript custom action?

Thanks!!

(Note: I realize there are ways to conditionally run exe files from withing InstallShield, but in this case the requirements are not supported by InstallShield - unless there is a way to use a VBScript custom action return value as a condition to run another file?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of messing around, I got it (actually found it in the InstallShield manual, and not Google, go figure :))!

This line of VBScript does the trick

```
disk1Path = Session.Property("SETUPEXEDIR")
```

The line above points to where ever the setup exe file was, so from there it's trivial to run any exe included with your install media.

Other useful ones I found, which I'll past here for reference are

```
'points to app data\downloaded install directory
MsgBox Session.Property("SourceDir")
'where the software wants to install to on the users system
MsgBox Session.Property("INSTALLDIR")
```

Not sure why it's so hard to find a good reference on MSI Standard properties (even just a list). The closest I found [was this](http://wix.mindcapers.com/wiki/MSI_Standard_Properties), but not all of them work (and not specifically for InstallShield at all). If anyone finds a good link with documentation about MIS Standard properties and their description please add a link here, so no one has to waste as much time on this as I did :).

Comment: Something like these? http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/InstallShield2011/IHelpPropReference.htm http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905.aspx