# How to get vbscript location

Tags: vbscript, windows-installer

If we are using this in custom action of an MSI, then `WScript.ScriptName` or `WScript` itself won't work.

The below will give the execution location (i.e., `msiexec.exe`) but not the VBScript or MSI file location.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strCurDir    = WshShell.CurrentDirectory
```

We can use below one to get the script location but it will work only in Immediate Execution but not in Deferred.

```
cdsd = Session.Property("SourceDir")
```

Please let me know if any other alternative to use in MSI Custom Actions, specially for deferred.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138831/getting-current-directory-in-vbscript

Comment: @Zam As stated by the OP, the `wscript` object is not available in an MSI (because the script isn't running via wscript.exe).

Answer (score -1):

**Hope this helps!** maybe? I can't tell if vbscript was or was not your intended usage.

```
SrcDirLen=Len(wscript.ScriptFullName)-Len(wscript.ScriptName)-1
SourceDir=Left(wscript.ScriptFullName, SrcDirLen)
```

I think this answer might be what you're looking for however.

```
SourceDir = Session.Property("SETUPEXEDIR") 'credit to link below
```

[How to find the setup location in an VBScript custom action for InstallShield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329475/how-to-find-the-setup-location-in-an-vbscript-custom-action-for-installshield)

after edits... I got nothing else man... Sorry, the MSI is a little out of my element. =) I tried.