# How can I get the path of a script and access another vbscript file in Install Shield?

Tags: vbscript, installshield

Install Shield. How to get a path of a script and call a vbscript method from different vbscript file?

Normally, outside install shield world I can use this this to get a executing script path:

`scriptPath = WScript.ScriptFullName`

and than do something like this to get a path of anoter vbscript file:
`commonModulePath = fso.BuildPath(scriptPath, "common.vbs")`.

But in install shield `scriptPath = WScript.ScriptFullName` is not working. Also using install shield properties like `SETUPEXENAME` doesn't give me working path.

Is it somehow possible to get access to another vbscript file  ?

I tried

- `scriptPath = WScript.ScriptFullName` (or before with `Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")` )
  it returns an error.
- install shield properties like `SETUPEXENAME` doesn't return file location (returns an error file not found)

Comment: Since your script is not running via WScript.exe, you cannot use `WScript` methods such as `Sleep` or `ScriptFullName`. You need something specific to InstallShield.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the setup location in an VBScript custom action for InstallShield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329475/how-to-find-the-setup-location-in-an-vbscript-custom-action-for-installshield)

Comment: Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31263647/how-to-get-vbscript-location). There may be an issue with deferred execution.